# Efficiently filter a large (100gb+) csv file (v2)

Tags: python, csv

EDIT: This question is followed up by [this question.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88885/efficiently-filter-a-large-100gb-csv-file-v3)

I'm in the process of filtering some very(!) large files (100gb+): I can't download files with a lower granularity. This is a followup from [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87258/filtering-multiple-large-2gb-csv-files-with-stock-prices).

The problem is as follows: I need to filter large files that look like the following (3b+ rows).

> ```
> TIC, Date, Time, Bid, Offer
> AAPL, 20090901, 09:45, 145, 145.5 
> AAPL, 20090902, 09:45, 145, 145.5
> AAPL, 20090903, 09:45, 145, 145.5
> ```

I filter based on TICKER+DATE combinations found in an external file. I have, on average, ~ 1200 dates of interest per firm for ~ 700 firms. The large file contains *all* dates for the firms of interest, for which I want to extract only a few dates of interest. The big files are split by month (2013-01, 2013-02 etc.).

> ```
> AAPL, 20090902
> AAPL, 20090903
> ```

A few changes were made since the previous post:

- I used the CSV module, as was suggested.
- I write the the rows to be retained to disk after each 5m rows.
- I iterate over the files using a try except statement.

I'm currently at 6 minutes of processing time for 30 million rows (1% of the file); I tested a few files and it works properly. However, with about 3 billion rows per file, that puts it at ~10 hours for one 120gb file. Seeing as I have about twelve files, I'm very curious whether I can get significant performance improvements by doing things differently.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

```
import os
import datetime
import csv
import re
ROOT_DIR = "H:/ROOT_DIR/"
SOURCE_FILES = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "10. Intradayfiles (source)/")
EXPORT_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "11. CSV Export (step 1  Extract relevant firmdates)/")
DATES_FILE = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "10. Dates of interest/firm_date_of_interest.csv")

# Build the original date dict
# For example:
#    d['AAPL'] is a list with ['20140901', '20140902', '20140901']
with open(DATES_FILE, "r") as csvfile:
    d = {}
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    reader.next()
    for line in reader:
        firm = line[1]
        date = line[2]
        if firm in d.keys():
            d[firm].append(date)
        else:
            d[firm] = [date]


def main():
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(SOURCE_FILES):
        num_files = len(files)
        for i, file in enumerate(files):
            print('File ' + str(i+1) + '/' + str(num_files) + '; ' + file)
            basename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            filepath = os.path.join(root, file)

            # Annotate files with 'DONE' after succesful processing: skip those
            if re.search("DONE", basename):
                continue

            start = datetime.datetime.now()
            rows_to_keep = []

            # Read the file, append only rows for which the dates occurs in the dictionary for that firm.
            with open(filepath, 'rb') as csvfile:
                startfile = datetime.datetime.now()
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
                saved = 0
                for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                    # Every 5 million rows, I save what we've extracted so far.
                    if i % 5000000 == 0:
                        if rows_to_keep:
                            with open(os.path.join(EXPORT_DIR, basename+' EXTRACT' + str(saved) + '.csv'), 'wb') as csvfile:
                                writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
                                for k, line in enumerate(rows_to_keep):
                                    writer.writerow(line)
                            saved += 1
                            rows_to_keep = []
                        file_elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - startfile
                        print("Took me " + str(file_elapsed.seconds) + ' seconds... for ' + str(i) + ' rows..')

                    # See if row[1] (the date) is in the dict, based on row[0] (the ticker)
                    try:
                        if row[1] in d[row[0]]:
                            rows_to_keep.append(row)
                    except KeyError:
                        continue
                    except IndexError:
                        continue
            os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root, os.path.splitext(file)[0]+'- DONE.csv'))
            elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - start
            print("Took me " + str(elapsed.seconds) + ' seconds...')

    return rows_to_keep

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: 1. How often do you need to carry out this kind of query? 2. How big are the results?

Comment: This is a one time thing (for a study), I'm interested in improving performance nonetheless as it likely will not be the last time I'll deal with big files. The output of one file is in the range of ~ 20 gb, still with a high granularity (price per second). After reducing the granularity of these files to 20-minute intervals with R, only 50 MB remains!

Comment: Are you sure this code works? I see a number of "basic" problems I would not expect to see in a working program.

Comment: @MVersteeg - so with those changes, now tha tyou are actually writing data to disk, and clearing out memory each time, is it faster?

Comment: You are correct, in prettying up the code for codereview I introduced quite a few naming errors. Am editing the post as we speak, pardon me!

Comment: I can't properly test the old code, as I'm getting a memory error due to an increased file size (the old code was written with a file from 2000; 2gb, I'm now working with a 2013 file; 120gb). Measuring in the script hints towards a ~ 30% improvement as the time per 1m rows is now 50 seconds vs. 70 seconds (prior code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the reading of the file a generator function:

```
def getLines(filename, d):
    with open(filename, "rb") as csvfile:
        datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in datareader:
            try:
                if row[1] in d[row[0]]:
                    yield row
            except KeyError:
                continue
            except IndexError:
                continue
```

This extracts the actual filter to a different function.

I would also suggest not accumulating the list of values to write out but instead use the generator to [create chunks directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/731620).

Answer (score 2):

Note: this is a partial review.

Your script is missing a shebang. I would suggest `#!/usr/bin/env pypy` to both support virtualenv and suggest that this script will benefit from pypy. It would also be nice to have a test case.

Here's what `pylint` complains about:

```
************* Module MVersteeg
C:  7, 0: Line too long (91/80) (line-too-long)
C:  8, 0: Line too long (86/80) (line-too-long)
C: 30, 0: Unnecessary parens after 'print' keyword (superfluous-parens)
C: 41, 0: Line too long (105/80) (line-too-long)
C: 50, 0: Line too long (124/80) (line-too-long)
C: 51, 0: Line too long (90/80) (line-too-long)
C: 57, 0: Line too long (111/80) (line-too-long)
C: 57, 0: Unnecessary parens after 'print' keyword (superfluous-parens)
C: 59, 0: Line too long (91/80) (line-too-long)
C: 67, 0: Line too long (107/80) (line-too-long)
C: 69, 0: Unnecessary parens after 'print' keyword (superfluous-parens)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
W: 42,41: Redefining name 'csvfile' from outer scope (line 13) (redefined-outer-name)
W: 29,15: Redefining built-in 'file' (redefined-builtin)
W: 44,16: Redefining name 'reader' from outer scope (line 15) (redefined-outer-name)
W: 52,39: Redefining name 'line' from outer scope (line 17) (redefined-outer-name)
W: 27,14: Redefining built-in 'dir' (redefined-builtin)
C: 26, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
R: 26, 0: Too many local variables (20/15) (too-many-locals)
W: 52,36: Unused variable 'k' (unused-variable)
W: 27,14: Unused variable 'dir' (unused-variable)
```

From my perspective, too much indentation suggests that you should factor out a few functions to make the code more readable. To make it more convenient, you could build a class that would store the inner state of your program.

```
print('File ' + str(i+1) + '/' + str(num_files) + '; ' + file)
```

This would be more efficient and readable if format strings were used.

I would also recommend using the `pv` program to monitor the file reading progress (in your current form, you're probably interested in running `pv -d $( pgrep -f yourscriptname )` in a separate terminal).

Please post a testcase so the program can be profiled and you can find your bottleneck.

Comment: Any tips on where I'd share such an immense data file? Would R code to generate a file suffice? Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Compress it, it should be smaller then. Actually, a few rows would already be enough for me to run the program and see its behavior.

Comment: Uploading as we speak, I'll post it within 2 hours with my updated code (based on the answers to this question). I very much appreciate your time and tips. Also, I'm working on a windows laptop: pv is not an option?

Comment: Being the Unix maniac I am, I would recommend using Cygwin, but I'm not sure if you'll feel comfortable using that. I know I would.

Comment: Though, I'm not sure if `pv -d` would work there - it would be better to rework the program to take the data from standard input and then a normal `pv` usage (without `-d`) would do. Anyway, that's my approach, YMMV ;)

Comment: Just posted my updated code and example sourcefile, would appreciate any tips!