# Aggregate prescriptions per drug in a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded, csv

I have a question that is similar in spirit to this [previously asked question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88885/efficiently-filter-a-large-100gb-csv-file-v3). Nonetheless, I can't seem to figure out a suitable solution.

**Input**: I have CSV data that looks like  (***FICTIONAL PATIENT DATA***)

```
id,prescriber_last_name,prescriber_first_name,drug_name,drug_cost
1000000001,Smith,James,AMBIEN,100
1000000002,Garcia,Maria,AMBIEN,200
1000000003,Johnson,James,CHLORPROMAZINE,1000
1000000004,Rodriguez,Maria,CHLORPROMAZINE,2000
1000000005,Smith,David,BENZTROPINE MESYLATE,1500
```

**Output**: from this I simply need to output each drug, the total cost which is summed over all prescriptions and I need to get a count of the unique number of prescribers.

```
drug_name,num_prescriber,total_cost
AMBIEN,2,300.0
CHLORPROMAZINE,2,3000.0
BENZTROPINE MESYLATE,1,1500.0
```

I was able to accomplish this pretty easily with Python. However, when I try to run my code with a much larger (1gb) input, my code does not terminate in a reasonable amount of time.

```
import sys, csv

def duplicate_id(id, id_list):
    if id in id_list:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def write_file(d, output):
    path = output
    # path = './output/top_cost_drug.txt'
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['drug_name', 'num_prescriber', 'total_cost']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for key, value in d.items():
            print(key, value)
            writer.writerow({'drug_name': key, 'num_prescriber': len(value[0]), 'total_cost': sum(value[1])})

def read_file(data):
    # TODO: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88885/efficiently-filter-a-large-100gb-csv-file-v3
    drug_info = {}
    with open(data) as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        next(readCSV)
        for row in readCSV:
            prescriber_id = row[0]
            prescribed_drug = row[3]
            prescribed_drug_cost = float(row[4])

            if prescribed_drug not in drug_info:
                drug_info[prescribed_drug] = ([prescriber_id], [prescribed_drug_cost])
            else:
                if not duplicate_id(prescriber_id, drug_info[prescribed_drug][0]):
                    drug_info[prescribed_drug][0].append(prescriber_id)
                    drug_info[prescribed_drug][1].append(prescribed_drug_cost)
                else:
                    drug_info[prescribed_drug][1].append(prescribed_drug_cost)
    return(drug_info)

def main():
    data = sys.argv[1]
    output = sys.argv[2]
    drug_info = read_file(data)
    write_file(drug_info, output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to refactor this to handle the larger input and was hoping someone on CodeReview could take a look and provide me some suggestions for how to solve this problem. Additionally, if you happen to see any other issues, I'd love the feedback.

Comment: This code is excessively long. Reduce the length first, worry about optimising afterwards. I’m not fluent with numpy but solving this should require **no more than ten lines of code**. Everything beyond that is excessive. [In R I’d solve this efficiently in four lines](https://gist.github.com/klmr/8272092170d0b19d98e5eb44fc9cec9f). It’s quite possible that numpy could do the same.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Pandas would be the tool of choice I think.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Performance

Your performance problem is primarily due to the `duplicate_id()` function, namely the `if id in id_list` test.  Testing whether an *n*-element list contains a particular item is O(*n*).  If you call that for *n* rows, then it's O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).  That would not be acceptable at all for large files.

Sorting the input would help bring it down to O(*n* log *n*).

But really, what you want is a solution with O(*n*) runtime, based on the hashing principle.  Use `dict`, `set`, or similar data structures so that each lookup takes constant time.

### Style

Use `csv.DictReader` to avoid the ugliness of discarding the first row using `next(readCSV)`, as well as the magic column numbers in `row[0]`, `row[3]`, and `row[4]`.

Instead of writing two cases depending on whether an entry already exists in a dictionary, use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects), [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), [`dict.get(key, default)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), or [`dict.setdefault(key, default)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

### Suggested solution

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import csv
import sys

def write_file(output_filename, drugs):
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, ('drug_name', 'num_prescriber', 'total_cost'))
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerows({
                'drug_name': drug_name,
                'num_prescriber': len(prescriber_totals),
                'total_cost': sum(prescriber_totals.values()),
            }
            for drug_name, prescriber_totals in drugs.items()
        )

def read_file(input_filename):
    drugs = defaultdict(Counter)
    with open(input_filename) as f:
        for row in csv.DictReader(f):
            drugs[row['drug_name']][row['id']] += float(row['drug_cost'])
    return drugs

def main(input_filename, output_filename):
    write_file(output_filename, read_file(input_filename))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Answer (score 8):

If your dataset is large, but not larger than memory, you might want to consider using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

def write_file(output_filename, drugs):
    drugs.to_csv(output_filename)

def read_file(input_filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(input_filename)
    drugs = df.groupby("drug_name").drug_cost.agg(["count", "sum"])
    drugs.columns = ["num_prescriber", "total_cost"]
    return drugs

def main(input_filename, output_filename):
    write_file(output_filename, read_file(input_filename))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Note that the structure is the same as the [pure Python answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/199661/98493) by [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success), for the same reasons.

If your dataset is larger than memory and you have already implemented your analysis in `pandas`, you might want to consider [`dask`](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/). In this case you would just need to replace `import pandas as pd` with `import dask.dataframe as pd`.

In the end you will be limited by the time your computer needs to read the whole dataset. For a 1 GB file this can vary from around 10 seconds (at 100 MB/s, a typical value for HDDs) over 2 seconds (at 500 MB/s, a fast SSD) down to 0.05 seconds (at 20 GB/s, a good DRAM, if it is on a RAM disk).

Answer (score 0):

One very important way to speed up the processing of large files like this is **streaming:** make sure you discard processed information as soon as possible. One simple way of doing this is a quick piece of preprocessing. You can do this in Python as well, but using highly optimised shell tools is probably going to save you a lot of time.

1. Remove the header with `tail -n +2 test.csv`.
2. Sort by the fourth column with `sort --key=4 --field-separator=, test.csv` (use `--output` if you want to overwrite the original file).

Now in your Python script save the sum for a drug to file once you encounter another drug name or end of file.

Also, rather than summing `prescribed_drug_cost` entries at the end simply add them to the running total as you go through the file. That way the resulting data structure is short and can be saved to file with minimal manipulation.

Comment: Hm, I added the shell script you suggested to my `run.sh` file, but when I run on the 1gb dataset, I'm still having the same issue I was before. Namely, the code is still not terminating in an acceptable amount of time. Are there any other ways you see to speed up the reading/processing steps?

Comment: Please read the whole post. I did say you have to change the script to "save the sum for a drug to file once you encounter another drug name or end of file."